# my php doesn't interpret postgresql or sql functions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

hello to everyone here ... please i need your help . i have some trouble with php and my SGBDs ... i have installed php mysql and apache separately . but when i launch a php program with mysql_connect it send a 500 internal error without response . i have changed mysql to postgresql but it is the same problems . i have also remove the comma before some line in php.ini but it's the same result ... there is a simple connection to the database code examples `

```
<?php

$link = pg_connect('localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
if (!$link) {`
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
pg_close($link);
```

`
and there is the result [the result of the code with 500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Z4x.png)
and there is my php.ini file [image of my php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKhS2.png)
thanks you

Comment: * Have you restart your apache ?

* Set display_errors directive to "On" in your php.ini    

* Create info.php in your document root, put "<? phpinfo(); ?>" into it.

access it from your browser, try to find word "pdo_pgsql" / "pdo_mysql" it's has appear correctly ?

* Look at your apache access_log and error_log files to get further info about your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Have you restart apache ?
- Set `display_errors` directive to `On` in your php.ini
- Create `info.php` in your document root, put `<? phpinfo(); ?>` into it.
  Open `info.php` from your browser, try to find word "pdo_pgsql" / "pdo_mysql". Has it appear correctly ?
- Dig into your apache `access_log` and `error_log` files to get further clue about your error.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php, you need to do

```
pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=mary user=USERNAME password=PASSWORD");
```

So the format is not correct and dbname is missing from your code.